# Execute a function in js file referred in source of a html script by using Webdriver/Katalon commands

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, katalon-recorder

**The below html script is part of an application page loaded using Katalon webdriver open command:**

Html script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="app_init" src="http://<hostname>:<port>/feature.js" ></script>
```

Function in feature.js:

```
var isFeatureReady = false;
function setFeatureReady(){
   isFeatureReady = true;
}
```

The plan is to execute the setFeatureReady function as part of webdriver javascript command to set the flag:

[image: Webdriver commands]

[image]

Please guide the way to trigger the function using commands

Comment: Not sure you can do this.  The driver's execute script method will have its own scope.  (You may have to include the entire script... a copy of it and then call it...)